# How to pass an instance of of a class from within that class

Tags: c#, class, pointers

I am wondering about something which can be achieved in c++ but I want to do it in C#.

How can I pass a "pointer" to a class, from within the class that contains the code, allowing me to write code in the form of the Foo.Bar()?

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Foo
    {
        MainClass MainClass;

        public void Bar()
        {
            var somethingElse = MainClass.A.SomethingElse;
            var somethingDifferent = MainClass.B.SomethingDifferent;
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public string Something;

        public SubClassA A = new SubClassA(this); // <<-- not valid in c#
        public SubClassB B = new SubClassB(this); // <<-- not valid in c#
    }

    public class SubClassA
    {
        private MainClass _MainClass;

        public SubClassA(MainClass mainClass)
        {
            _MainClass = mainClass;
        }

        public string SomethingElse {
            get {
                return _MainClass.Something + " Else";
            }
        }
    }

    public class SubClassB
    {
        private MainClass _MainClass;

        public SubClassB(MainClass mainClass)
        {
            _MainClass = mainClass;
        }

        public string SomethingDifferent
        {
            get
            {
                return _MainClass.Something + " Different";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should state that I know I can restructure my code in a million ways to achieve a workable result, but I have a specific question I am hoping to answer! :)

Thanks

Comment: implement your property as static, which will allow it to be accessed on the type name rather than an instance

Comment: @DStanley The OP has already asked a specific question. He is simply restating that it's THIS question he wants asnwered.

Comment: @slippyr4 I can't see how that would work? It needs an instance?

Comment: @Beakie i initially misunderstood the question - the OP's desire to use the form Foo.Bar() (where Foo is a type) implies the need for Bar() to be static (because you can't call an instance method on a type). Now I think that the "Foo" part is either ambiguous or a typo.

Comment: To answer your question: you could pass `this` in its constructor / method.

Comment: @slippyr4 Actually, I could have a property of Foo called Foo. Then Foo.Bar() would be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need to do is move the initialization expression out of the field declaration and into a constructor:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string Something;

    public SubClassA A;
    public SubClassB B;

    public MainClass()
    {
        A = new SubClassA(this);
        B = new SubClassB(this);
    }
}
```

Note:

- Please stop using public fields. They make me sad, and it's a Friday afternoon, when I should be happy.
- "Leaking" a `this` pointer during construction can be dangerous. If whatever you're calling (the constructors in this case) calls back into the object, it will be running code when you haven't finished initializing. It's a bit like calling a virtual method in a constructor - it works, but it makes the code brittle.
- Subclass. You keep using this word. I do not think it means what you think it means.
- You never initialize `Foo.MainClass`, so your `Bar()` method is going to fail with a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: THANKS!

1) I used public fields cause the syntax is smaller for this example.
2) I am well aware of the dangers. I am talking hypothetically here.
3) I know that a subclass is a derived class :) I thought the name might make sense for the example. Perhaps child would have been better :)
4) Again, this is just a chunk of code to make my point. I won't be running it! :)

Thanks again, your answer is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: PSA, dont make Jon sad! Say "NO" to public fields! Unless they are in Cheapside.

Comment: Ha... lets all put public fields behind us. 55 mins and I am outta work and straight down the public house!

Answer (score 4):

In `MainClass`, you need to initialize `SubClassA` A and `SubClassB` B inside the `MainClass` constructor (where `this` will have a valid reference).  The place where you're currently initializing those members is outside the context of a created `MainClass` object (hence the error).